# Multi-linear regression in R error: 0 (non-NA) cases. How do I get this to work?

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying to perform a multilinear regression analysis in R. I have a bunch of predictor variables that I had to centre (eg. variableA - mean(variableA)).
Now when I plugged this into my lm(), it comes back with the following error:

> 0 (non-NA) cases

From the research I've already done, it seems to be due to have NAs, which one of my variables does have (all NA's actually.) But before I centered this one, they were all character name values as opposed to numeric. But when I try to plug in the variable value NOT centered, I get an answer..

I do need to use this predictor variable of NA's (that became NA's after centering) as it's required in the question. Any suggestiong would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I'm fairly new at R so sorry if most of that was nonsense.

Comment: are there any NA values to start with? if there is, mean(variableA) will return NA and it just propagates

Comment: At least give us the results of `str(yourdataframe)`. Probably your character variable is a factor variable and you cannot center a factor variable.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I checked my str and you're right, my character variable is a factor variable! So is the answer just not to center it, even though I'll be centering my other variables?

Comment: You cannot center a factor. In the regression, an effect for every factor is estimated.